# How to detect props changes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components: `Radiobuttons` and `RadioOutput`, where `RadioOutput` accepts a props from `Radiobuttons`. On click of the radio buttons, I can console log the props change as follows:

`Radiobuttons.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RadioOutput from './RadioOutput';

const Radiobuttons = () => {
    const [cause, setCause] = useState(null);
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setCause(e.currentTarget.value)
    };
    return (
        <>
            <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML" onClick={handleClick}/>
            <label for="html">HTML</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS" onClick={handleClick}/>
            <label for="css">CSS</label><br />
            <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript" onClick={handleClick}/>
            <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
            <RadioOutput cause={cause}/>
        </>
    )
};

export default Radiobuttons;
```

`RadioOutput.js`:

```
const RadioOutput = ({cause}) => {
    console.log(cause);
    return null;
};

export default RadioOutput;
```

My question is, is there a way I can detect the changes of `cause` inside `RadioOutput`? Maybe something like this:

```
const RadioOutput = ({cause}) => {
    // on change of cause, do something;
    return null;
};
```

Comment: You're already doing that `RadioOutput` gets re-called every time the cause changes, demonstrated by the fact the console.log occurs every time a change is made.

Comment: Can I do something inside RadioOutput like `if (cause changes) {do something}`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do when cause changes? Update the UI?

Comment: I have a dropdown which values are populated based on change of `cause`, and I'd like to reset the selected dropdown value to `null` whenever `cause` changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RadioOutput` will automatically re-render whenever `causes` value changes. But if you want to perform some side effects that depends only on `cause` value change, you can use `useEffect` hook.

`useEffect` will execute the function whenever `cause` value changes.

More about `useEffect` here
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

const RadioOutput = ({cause}) => {

    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log("runs whenever cause changes")
    },[cause])

    return null;
};
```